# I want to make new variable search after making a date search variable, but using the found set from the search date

Tags: global-variables, filemaker

I have a problem, new to filemaker.  I want to make new variable search after making a date search variable, but using the found set from the search date.

show all records

```
show custom dialog [search :: xsearch category; search:: start date; search :: end date]
perform find
enter find mode
set variable [$date; value: machine transactions 2::service date]
perform find
```

What happens, is that I will find the category search "plotter" okay
but when I search again with the $date range, it will start to search again the my whole database and show also the other categories

Comment: The script you posted makes very little sense. In general, you can use Constrain Found Set instead of Perform Find to search only in the current found set. Or - preferably - do a single find using both your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Constrain Found Set" script step instead of "Perform Find" in the second search.